# Contours too tight in geom_density_2d

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like the contours to be all the way around the data but instead I have small density regions. Does anyone know how to resolve this? I will attach my code and data. I have tried different args but I just can't seem to make it change. I guess one way of thinking about what I would like is a 100% contour than a 90% contour then 80% and so on.

```
ggplot(df3, aes(x, y)) +
stat_density_2d(size = 1, aes(color = "Contours")) +
geom_path(data = df3, aes(color = "Parameter Path"), lwd = 1) +
geom_point(data = df3, aes(color = "Accepted Values"), size = 2) +
labs(x = expression(mu), y = expression(phi)) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 18),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 18),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20, angle = 0, vjust = 0.5),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = c(0.14, 0.84),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey96", size = 1, linetype = 
"solid"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 16),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold")) +
guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE), 
color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA))) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0.065, 0.135, 0.01),
                 limits = c(0.065, 0.135)) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.03, 0.055, 0.005),
                 limits = c(0.03, 0.055)) +
ggtitle("Confidence Ellipse") +
scale_color_manual("Results", values = c("red1", "deepskyblue2", "black"), 
breaks = c("Accepted Values", "Parameter Path", "Contours"))
```

[image]

Data:

```
> x0
 [1] 0.08358176 0.06553959 0.08701262 0.13261197 0.11827522 0.12895425         
     0.07641320 0.09780957 0.12004418 0.10330265 0.13115285 0.11239738
[13] 0.09539895 0.09978812 0.08133239 0.08256920 0.06962943 0.11592930 
     0.06910299 0.08968366 0.09268526 0.09354692 0.09407394 0.10241154
[25] 0.11241420 0.10679109 0.10047328 0.08391576 0.09663064 0.09601004 
     0.08067915 0.09624377 0.10755340 0.09217993 0.10787710 0.08061391
[37] 0.08068861 0.08953676 0.09189470 0.12449563 0.09883104 0.12972641 
     0.11940337 0.11907046 0.10960429 0.09448710

> y0
 [1] 0.04219829 0.03586581 0.03353818 0.05380570 0.05151715 0.05587795 
     0.03240938 0.03869719 0.04355228 0.03748867 0.05029841 0.04462947
[13] 0.04057039 0.03691092 0.03801298 0.03997664 0.03429455 0.04798272 
     0.03641225 0.04115275 0.04029572 0.04043962 0.03793742 0.03940454
[25] 0.04468192 0.04189995 0.04296391 0.03632054 0.04192571 0.03698961 
     0.03703587 0.04008437 0.04824601 0.03933985 0.04131714 0.03589466
[37] 0.03665176 0.03872114 0.04056889 0.04843315 0.04547021 0.04853519 
     0.04710753 0.04888831 0.04833231 0.03744968

df3 = data.frame(x = x0, y = y0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I run your code **without any changes** I get the below plot which I think is what you are after.

I import the data above as per below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

```
y0 <- t(read.table(text = "0.04219829 0.03586581 0.03353818 0.05380570 0.05151715 0.05587795 0.03240938 0.03869719 0.04355228 0.03748867 0.05029841 0.04462947 0.04057039 0.03691092 0.03801298 0.03997664 0.03429455 0.04798272 0.03641225 0.04115275 0.04029572 0.04043962 0.03793742 0.03940454 0.04468192 0.04189995 0.04296391 0.03632054 0.04192571 0.03698961 0.03703587 0.04008437 0.04824601 0.03933985 0.04131714 0.03589466 0.03665176 0.03872114 0.04056889 0.04843315 0.04547021 0.04853519 0.04710753 0.04888831 0.04833231 0.03744968",
                 sep=" ",header=FALSE,dec="."))


x0 <- t(read.table(text = "0.08358176 0.06553959 0.08701262 0.13261197 0.11827522 0.12895425 0.07641320 0.09780957 0.12004418 0.10330265 0.13115285 0.11239738 0.09539895 0.09978812 0.08133239 0.08256920 0.06962943 0.11592930 0.06910299 0.08968366 0.09268526 0.09354692 0.09407394 0.10241154 0.11241420 0.10679109 0.10047328 0.08391576 0.09663064 0.09601004 0.08067915 0.09624377 0.10755340 0.09217993 0.10787710 0.08061391 0.08068861 0.08953676 0.09189470 0.12449563 0.09883104 0.12972641 0.11940337 0.11907046 0.10960429 0.09448710",
                   sep=" ",header=FALSE,dec="."))

df3 = data.frame(x = x0, y = y0)
```

I run your code **(without any changes)**

I get the below `warning messages`

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density2d). 
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

> Possibly a version issue:

```
version.string R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
> packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] ‘3.1.1’
```

[image]

### If I run with your version of `ggplot2`

```
> packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] ‘3.0.0’
```

> I still get the same plot as above with the same code.

Additionally you could try `geom_density_2d` rather with no frills and see if at least that generates the contours as expected:

```
ggplot(df3, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_density_2d(size=1,aes(color = "Contours"))+
  geom_point(data = df3, aes(color = "Accepted Values"), size = 2)
```

Comment: The warning message is from chopping out one anomaly point. This is exactly what I wanted to see do you know why my code produces something so different? My ggplot2 version is 3.0.0

Comment: It's hard for me to debug on my side as it seems to work fine, even with your `3.0.0` version, tried to add some basic code to help :)

Comment: How strange that it works perfectly for you. It's for a project of mine so if you could perhaps export as a pdf for me and then send that to me through an email that would be great. I did have this problem with a basic code too.

Comment: It is very odd. Yeah that's beyond the purpose & scope of SO. I would try install the latest version of `R` and `gpplot2` that should do the trick.

Comment: UPDATE: I have to correct plot as you have and I was getting the wrong contours because when I was plotting the `geom_path` and `geom_point` the `data` was using vectors for `x` and `y` that had thousands of duplicates. Changing the `data.frame(x = unique(x0), y = unique(y0))` sorted everything out. Thank you for your assistance. It was all a silly mistake which is common for me :)